# locking of copy_[to/from]_user() in linux kernel

Tags: c, locking, linux-kernel, mutex

as stated in: http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-hacking.html#routines-copy this functions "can" sleep.

So, do I always have to do a lock (e.g. with mutexes) when using this functions or are there exceptions?

I'm currently working on a module and saw some Kernel Oops at my system, but cannot reproduce them. I have a feeling they are fired because I'm currently do no locking around copy_[to/from]_user(). Maybe I'm wrong, but it smells like it has something to do with it.

I have something like:

```
static unsigned char user_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
static ssize_t mcom_write (struct file *file, const char *buf, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {
    ssize_t retval;
    size_t writeCount = (length < BUFFER_SIZE) ? length : BUFFER_SIZE;
    memset((void*)&user_buffer, 0x00, sizeof user_buffer);
    if (copy_from_user((void*)&user_buffer, buf, writeCount)) {
        retval = -EFAULT;
        return retval;
    }
    *offset += writeCount;
    retval = writeCount;        
    cleanupNewline(user_buffer);    
    dispatch(user_buffer);
    return retval;
}
```

Is this save to do so or do I need locking it from other accesses, while copy_from_user is running?

It's a char device I read and write from, and if a special packet in the network is received, there can be concurrent access to this buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do locking iff the kernel side data structure that you are copying to or from might go away otherwise - but it is that data structure you should be taking a lock on.

Comment: hi thanks, I think I understood what you mean, can you take a look at my code above and tell me if this is ok, I just write into a local buffer. So if i'm correct I have to protect the buffer from any other read/writes as long as my copy_from_users has access to the data structure, right?

Comment: @evildead: The buffer is static so you don't have to worry about it going away - however if other kernel code can access that buffer simultaneously, you will probably need locking to ensure that it doesn't see the buffer in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your function `mcom_write` is a procfs write function (or similar) right? In that case, you most likely are writing to the procfs file, **your program being blocked until `mcom_write` returns**, so even if `copy_[to/from]_user` sleeps, your program wouldn't change the buffer.

You haven't stated how your program works so it is hard to say anything. If your program is multithreaded and one thread writes while another can change its data, then yes, you need locking, but between the threads of the user-space program not your kernel module.

If you have one thread writing, then your write to the procfs file would be blocked until `mcom_write` finishes so no locking is needed and your problem is somewhere else (unless there is something else that is wrong with this function, but it's not with `copy_from_user`)

Comment: sorry I'm kinda new to this. Its not anything from procfs I think, its just a simple char device under /dev. And I have concurrent access to that data structure, from user and kernel space. (If a packet on the network appears (a hard and then a soft_irq is fired?) this function is jumped and can modify data.

Comment: I'm in java (scala) from userspace, and I use a datatype called RandomAccessFile, this does not block if the char device is open by another thread, imho. But I think its the only way to access the char device from within java. I searched for it and only found RandomAccessFile is working correct. Maybe I'm wrong with that. Anyway, concurrent access can appear in the kernel also from the network interrupts.

Comment: procfs and /dev devices kinda work similar. I need to clarify something though. When you write to the file, there is a buffer you are writing from. For example, if you have some data structures, you create a string containing those data, then the string is a copy of the data structure and if others change the structure, that string (which is the buffer for writing to the file) does not change. So no locking is needed. If you are writing directly from your data structures, then yes locking is absolutely necessary.